# Python. Grouping dictionaries in a list together, creating lists of dicts inside a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list that has multiple dictionaries. Some of these dictionaries I do not need. In the end, I want to have all the dictionaries that have the key 'start' in them. Moreover, I want the dicts with 'start' in them grouped together (in a list) in such a way that everytime a sequence of dicts with ‘start’ in (or only one occurrence of ‘start’) them is interrupted with a dict without 'start' in it, the next list with ‘start’ dictionaries is created, and so on.

```
[{'key_one': ‘value_one’, 'key_two': 'value_two'},
{'num': ‘1’, 'start': 's1’},
{'num': ‘2’, 'start': 's2’},
{'num': '3, 'start': 's3’},
{'num': '4', 'start': 's4’},
{'num': '5, 'start': ‘s5’},
{'num': '6, 'start': 's6’},
{'num': '7', 'start': 's7’ },
{'num': '8', 'start': 's8’},
{'num': '9', 'start': 's9’},
{'num': '10', 'start': 's10’},
{'key_one': ‘value_one’, 'key_two': 'value_two'},
{'num': '11', 'start': 's11’},
{'num': '12', 'start': 's12’},
{'num': '13', 'start': 's13’},
{'num': '14', 'start': 's14’},
{'num': '15', 'start': 's15’},
{'key_one': ‘value_one’, 'key_two': 'value_two'},
{'num': '16', 'start': 's16’},
{'num': '17', 'start': 's17},
{'num': '18', 'start': 's18}]
```

So in this example, the output should be:

```
[[{'num': ‘1’, 'start': 's1’},
{'num': ‘2’, 'start': 's2’},
{'num': '3, 'start': 's3’},
{'num': '4', 'start': 's4’},
{'num': '5, 'start': ‘s5’},
{'num': '6, 'start': 's6’},
{'num': '7', 'start': 's7’ },
{'num': '8', 'start': 's8’},
{'num': '9', 'start': 's9’},
{'num': '10', 'start': 's10’}]

[{'num': '11', 'start': 's11’},
{'num': '12', 'start': 's12’},
{'num': '13', 'start': 's13’},
{'num': '14', 'start': 's14’},
{'num': '15', 'start': 's15’}]

[{'num': '16', 'start': 's16’},
{'num': '17', 'start': 's17},
{'num': '18', 'start': 's18}]]
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please give a shorter example.

Comment: Your dictionary is littered with syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define your original list of dicts as `L`, and the desired final result (list of lists of dicts) as `R`. `sub_list` is a temporary list used to collect the chunks:

```
R = []
sub_list = []
for d in L:
    if 'start' in d:
        sub_list.append(d)
    else:
        if sub_list:
            R.append(sub_list)
            sub_list = []
print R
```

The additional condition `if sub_list:` also makes sure you never have an empty `sub_list` in your `R`.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
old_list = [{'key_one': 'value_one', 'key_two': 'value_two'}, {'num': '1', 'start': 's1'}, {'num': '2', 'start': 's2'}, {'num': '3', 'start': 's3'}, {'num': '4', 'start': 's4'}, {'num': '5', 'start': 's5'}, {'num': '6', 'start': 's6'}, {'num': '7', 'start': 's7' }, {'num': '8', 'start': 's8'}, {'num': '9', 'start': 's9'}, {'num': '10', 'start': 's10'}, {'key_one': 'value_one', 'key_two': 'value_two'}, {'num': '11', 'start': 's11'}, {'num': '12', 'start': 's12'}, {'num': '13', 'start': 's13'}, {'num': '14', 'start': 's14'}, {'num': '15', 'start': 's15'}, {'key_one': 'value_one', 'key_two': 'value_two'}, {'num': '16', 'start': 's16'}, {'num': '17', 'start': 's17'}, {'num': '18', 'start': 's18'}]
new_list = [[]]
for dictionary in new_list:
    if 'start' in dictionary.keys():
        new_list[-1].append(dictionary)
    elif new_list[-1]:
        new_list.append([])
new_list = new_list[:-1]
```